# helm get syntax for getting the chart of a release

Tags: kubernetes-helm

`helm get --help` says that...

> *[`helm get`]* can be used to get extended information about the release, including:
>
> - The values used to generate the release
> - The chart used to generate the release
> - The generated manifest file

The *extended information* bit is somehow foggy but whatever.

Now:

- *The values used to generate the release* maps to `helm get values -a releasename`
- *The chart used to generate the release*... **maps to?!?**
- *The generated manifest file* maps to `helm get manifest releasename`

Thanks!

**Edit 1**: looking at one answer below, it struck me that by *chart* I mean the whole directory with the artifacts inside (templates, `Chart.yaml` etc. etc.) but maybe the documentation means just the *name* of the chart?

Answer (score 4):

Use [helm list](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/helm/helm_list.md) to get release chart

`helm list releasename --output yaml`

```
>helm list master --output yaml

Next: ""
Releases:
- AppVersion: "1.0"
  Chart: environment-0.1.0-master
  Name: master
  Namespace: master
  Revision: 42
  Status: DEPLOYED
  Updated: Thu Dec 13 16:33:08 2018
```

Comment: Thanks, what I'm after is the whole chart thing (including artifacts), not info about the release. Considering that `helm get manifest` gives back the manifests themselves, I was assuming that `helm get ...` would also help me get the original chart used for deploying the release.

Comment: The original chart is environment-0.1.0-master in this case, what information are you trying to get ?

Comment: *A chart is a collection of files that describe a related set of Kubernetes resources* (from [here](https://docs.helm.sh/developing_charts/)). The thing in the output of your command above is the chart name/id (I guess), not the chart itself. Like `helm get manifest` provides actual manifest files, I was assuming that some command would give me back the chart, not just the name/id.

Comment: You can use `helm inspect` to inspect a specific chart

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear from the beginning.
Suppose I create a *chart* on my laptop, and then use it to install a *release* in the Kubernetes cluster. At this point, a colleague from her laptop can *get* the *release* but cannot retrieve whatever artifacts were used to generate that *release* because they are on my laptop and seem to be stored nowhere in helm. I was looking for a way to retrieve the *chart* from the *release*.

Comment: Chart packages are usually stored and shared in chart repository (https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/chart_repository.md)

Comment: which is another way to say that no, it's not possible to retrieve the chart from a release: if you want something near to that, you have to setup a separate chart repository. Note that tiller does indeed store the whole thing I was looking for, only in a format that is go-specific and cannot be exported without coding.

Comment: hmm, the resulting <chart name>-<version> sure is a pain in the ass. I just want the version.

Answer (score 4):

In Helm **3**, you can use:

```sh
helm get all <RELEASE_NAME> -n <NAME_SPACE>
```