# Retrieve chart artifacts from a release

Tags: kubernetes-helm

This is a complementary question with respect to [helm get syntax for getting the chart of a release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53763636/helm-get-syntax-for-getting-the-chart-of-a-release).

I'd like to understand whether the following use case is supported with helm or not:

1. Alice creates a **chart** `foo` on her laptop, which is stored in a directory in the laptop's filesystem:

   ```
   [alice-laptop]$ helm create foo
   # Alice fiddles with contents of foo, like Chart.yaml, templates...
   ```
2. Alice generates a **release** of `foo` from her laptop, calling the instance `bar`:

   ```
   [alice-laptop]$ helm install -n bar foo
   ```
3. Alice goes in a vacation, hiking on the mountains. Good for her!
4. While she is away, Bob is asked to make some changes to **release** `bar` and also start another **release** `tut` for safe fiddling. So Bob would like to run some command to retrieve **chart** `foo` (not just the name, but all artifacts!) that were used at the time of generation of `bar`, to make changes on them and use helm the right way:

   ```
   [bob-laptop]$ helm whatever-command-if-possible bar
   # ideally Bob has a `foo' directory now and can fiddle with it...

   # ... to make the required changes for release `bar'
   [bob-laptop]$ helm update bar foo

   # ... and to install another release `tut'
   [bob-laptop]$ helm install -n tut foo
   ```

Bob reads that `get` might be the right tool for the job `whatever-command-if-possible` above, but doesn't really know whether this is the case or not, or if this can be done at all.

Comment: helm get all RELEASE_NAME [flags]   ---   This command prints a human readable collection of information about the notes, hooks, supplied values, and generated manifest file of the given release. -- https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_get_all/

Answer (score 1):

No, the following use case is not possible.

You can only retrieve a specific **chart** that was used to create a **release** from [chart Repository](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/chart_repository.md)

You may want to read [share your charts with others](https://docs.helm.sh/developing_charts/#managing-chart-repositories) section

First of all, Alice and Bob should have a common **chart repository**. In this example they're using a public GCP Bucket **common-charts**.
[image: charts-example]

Before going on vacation, after Alice creates and finishes to work on chart (and before creating a release from it), she should **package** the chart.

`[alice-laptop]$ helm package foo`

This will create **foo-0.1.0.tgz** chart package.

`Successfully packaged chart and saved it to: C:\home\stack\foo-0.1.0.tgz`

Alice creates [index file](https://docs.helm.sh/developing_charts/#the-index-file) and uploads package and index file to GCP Bucket

```
[alice-laptop]$ mkdir common-charts
[alice-laptop]$ mv foo-0.1.0.tgz common-charts
[alice-laptop]$ helm repo index common-charts --url https://common-charts.storage.googleapis.com

[alice-laptop]$ gsutil cp common-charts\* gs://common-charts
Copying file://common-charts\foo-0.1.0.tgz [Content-Type=application/x-tar]...
Copying file://common-charts\index.yaml [Content-Type=application/octet-stream]...
\ [2 files][  1.8 KiB/  1.8 KiB]
Operation completed over 2 objects/1.8 KiB.
```

While she is away, Bob can download **foo** chart from **common-charts** chart repository, untar it and apply changes.

```
[bob-laptop]$ helm repo add common-charts https://common-charts.storage.googleapis.com
[bob-laptop]$ helm search foo
NAME                    CHART VERSION   APP VERSION     DESCRIPTION
common-charts/foo       0.1.0           1.0             A Helm chart for Kubernetes

[bob-laptop]$ helm fetch common-charts/foo --untar
[bob-laptop]$ ls -la
drwxr-xr-x 1 bob 1049089   0 Dec 20 12:15 foo/
```

Bob can also [add new charts to existing repo](https://docs.helm.sh/developing_charts/#add-new-charts-to-an-existing-repository) and Alice can download them  when she is back.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for taking the time to compose such a thorough answer. The OP contained a question that was like "Is this use case possible or not", which is not "totally" answered: you are describing one way to implement the use case in an alternative way, not stating that my use case cannot be realized as-is. Long story short, if you can bother putting a crisp statement at the beginning providing a direct answer to my question (like "No, the use case is not supported as described" or so) I can accept your answer. Thanks!